# Unable to upload jpg image without exif to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, jpeg

I'm trying to upload jpg images on AWS S3 using the golang aws client (github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.43.10) as follow:

```
func (s *S3) PutObject(bucket string, key string, body io.ReadSeeker) (*s3.PutObjectOutput, error) {
    objectInput := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Body:        body,
        Bucket:      aws.String(bucket),
        ContentType: aws.String("image/jpeg"),
        Key:         aws.String(key),
    }

    return s.Client.PutObject(objectInput)
}
```

Some of the images i'm trying to upload do not have exifs and in that case upload fails without any error, the image just don't pop in the bucket i've specified.
The only workaround i've found until now is to rename the destination key suffix from jpg to jpeg.

It's not an authorization issue since i'm able to upload the other images.
Is there something that i am missing ? Or does AWS checks exifs "under the hood" and rejects my images ? Aws documentation doesn't seem to mention anything of the sort.

Comment: The uploads almost certainly aren't failing without error. Double check the key you're supplying, the body, and the return code from PutObject.

Comment: "Or does AWS checks exifs "under the hood" and rejects my images"  No, AWS S3 does not attempt to parse any object data.